# Adjusting dates in autoplot in R

Tags: r, plot, forecasting, forecast

I am using `autoplot` function from the `forecast` package to show the out-of-sample on step ahead forecast

```
# fit ARIMA model 
model1 <- auto.arima(y, seasonal=TRUE, stationary=TRUE)
```

where `y` is a ts object at a monthly frequency from 1960-01-01 to 2017-12-01.

Then I use the `autoplot` function to see the forecast of the model which in my case I set to be the next month (that is should be 2018-01-01)

I use the following command:

```
autoplot(forecast(model1, h=1))
```

Which gives me the following pic:

[image]

Due to a large number of observations before the forecasting period, it looks that my forecast is not very clear.

How should adjust my autoplot function to make the my forecast appear ? I am thinking to focus only on the last twelve months, but I don't know how should modify the `autplot` function

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass scale_x_continuous and subset it. Here is an example using goog dataset and a naive forecast.

```
library(forecast); library(tidyverse)
autoplot(naive(goog200, h = 20)) + 
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(150,300))
```

Comment: It partially works. I say partially because `y` is a `ts` object and the x-axis represent dates. So, it does not look particularly good having a continues number.